Overlaying UTM Grid on a True North-Aligned Map: Which Projection to use?
I’m working on a topographic map and aiming to recreate the style of Canadian topographic maps, specifically how they integrate a True North-aligned map frame with a UTM coordinate grid.

The map area is located in UTM Zone 34N (Western Bulgaria), with the following extents:

Geographic coordinates: 42°27' to 42°39' N latitude, 23°09' to 23°21' E longitude
UTM coordinates: 677000 mE to 694000 mE, 4702000 mN to 4724000 mN

My Objective:

I want the vertical edges of the map frame to point to True North (TN), as seen in traditional geographic projections.
I also want to overlay a 1km UTM grid (from EPSG:32634 – UTM Zone 34N).
The UTM grid, in this case, should appear slightly tilted (to the right) due to the grid convergence angle, which I’ve calculated to be approximately 1°32’ at the center of my map.

The Problem:
If I set my project CRS to EPSG:32634 (UTM Zone 34N), the UTM grid aligns perfectly horizontal and vertical, but the map frame no longer points to True North. This is not the look I want.
On the other hand, I initially tried using EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator), but this caused significant distortions:

At a map scale of 1:50,000, the 1000 m UTM grid lines expanded to about 1350 m, effectively becoming something like 1:38 000.

What I’ve Considered So Far:

ChatGPT suggested keeping the map CRS as EPSG:32634 for accurate scaling and minimal deformation but manually rotating the map (in Layout Manager) to align the map frame to True North. This effectively tilts the UTM grid as expected.
I’d like to confirm whether this is the best approach or if there’s a preferred geographic projection that would naturally produce a TN-aligned frame while minimizing deformations for my specific area of interest.

Summary of Questions:

Which CRS or projection should I use to ensure the map frame aligns with True North and the UTM grid appears correctly tilted?
Is manually rotating the map in EPSG:32634 the most practical solution?
Are there other geographic projections typically used for this type of map design as well as this geographic area (Southeast Europe)?

Disclaimer: I'm a hobbyist in cartography, not a GIS professional.

One question per Question, please, as per the [Tour].

If you want the map to use UTM, then yes, the UTM grid lines will be oriented with the page/paper edges. The graticule, latitude/longitude, lines will be tipped. The only place that true/geodetic north is directly 'up' on the page in UTM is at the central meridian.

I want the map to have a UTM grid as an overlay, not necessarily the map itself to be a UTM projection.

In the sample map, true north is not aligned to grid north. So...if you want true north to be 'up' everything in the map, you need to use a cylindrical projection where the pole is a straight line as long as the equator (aka a rectangular shape).
